# Android OpenCV 2.4.2 Tutorials Eclipse - cannot dlopen camera wrapper library

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying to get all the OpenCV tutorials running, but so far, cannot get Tutorial 2, face-detection, color blob detection, working;  I can, however, run Tutorial 0, 1, 3, and 4.  I have corrected a number of errors, including having to add all the include paths:

```
<includepath>${NDKROOT}/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include</includepath>
<includepath>C:\android-ndk-r8b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.6\libs\armeabi\include</includepath>
<includepath>${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include</includepath>
<includepath>C:\android-opencv\sdk\native\jni\include</includepath>
<includepath>C:\android-ndk-r8b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\lib\gcc\arm-linux-androideabi\4.6.x-google\include</includepath>
```

I have also updated the Application.mk files to use APP_ABI := armeabi, and this allowed Tuts 3 and 4 to work.  The Android versions are all correct.

Some of the examples don't use C++ code at all, and yet they still fail on being unable to open the camera wrapper library.  This is after it appears to go through a sequence of trying to link each version of the library, such as libnative_camera_r2.3.3, r2.2.0, etc.
It was doing this also for Tuts 3 and 4 before I updated the APP_ABI := armeabi-v7 to APP_ABI := armeabi, but this does not correct the problem for the other Tuts.

Please help.  I am new to the Android NDK, and only have Open CV experience using in Windows. Thanks in advance.

I did notice that in the tutorials that I can run, the phone camera is of type Camera and is opened using .open() command; the cameras that will not run, the phone camera is declared as type VideoCapture, and that apparently needs the wrapper library.  Just not sure how to get that onto the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it is something to do with my phone that I am testing it on: Samsung Galaxy S.  I found someone else with a very similar problem: [Camera not working](http://answers.opencv.org/question/1574/camera-not-working/)

Rather than go through the superhuman programming leaps that Pete went through to solve this, I decided to try it on another phone, an HTC slide.  Lo and behold, all the tutorials worked fine with no problems, no recoding.

In the interest of getting things done, I am going to work with the HTC slide for my project.
If anyone comes across a better solution, please let me know!

UPDATE: I did some more research: http://answers.opencv.org/question/1223/android-opencv-support/
It appears that OpenCV Android Native Camera is not supported by all devices due to it being modified by hardware paltform vendors.

FINAL UPDATE: I did some more experimenting with the tutorials, and had a major DUH moment. You can actually use OpenCV without using the OpenCV Native Camera.  I tested this by converting the SampleViewBase class in Tutorial 3 to replace the SampleCvViewBase class in the face detection sample, and it worked great!  The major trick was converting the data during the processImage call so:

```
capture.retrieve(mRgba, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA);
capture.retrieve(mGray, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_GREY_FRAME);
```

became

```
Mat mYuv = new Mat(getFrameHeight()+getFrameHeight()/2, getFrameWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
mYuv.put(0, 0, data);
Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuv, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2RGB, 4);
Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 0);
```

Major help came from another stackoverflow article: [Capture camera preview for using in OpenCV. Converting to RGB and Gray Mat's. Java. Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741825/capture-camera-preview-for-using-in-opencv-converting-to-rgb-and-gray-mats-ja)

In case I don't see you, good afternoon, good evening, and good night!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of your phone because i could run all the samples perfectly in my Samsung Galaxy Note Phone. Try changing your phone and then run the samples.